Sleep mode of SGP40 sensor
I'm trying to develop a system which has a feature to monitor air quality using a SGP40. I want this board to be in sleep mode most of the time and only wake up if the sensor detects alarming measurement. The board is powered by a 12V battery.
My thought is that the SGP40 will work as a triggering source that wakes up the MCU. Knowing that this sensor consumes around 3mA@3V in continuous operating state, I want to know:

Is there a way to make it even more power efficient?
Can this sensor also go into sleep mode and if it does, how will it detect the alarming measurement and send a wake-up signal to the MCU?


Many low-power MCU's have incredibly low-powered independent timers that can wake up the main mcu as well as other devices.  I'd look into that instead of trying to modify your sensor.  Typical strategy is to take a sample every N hours/minutes/seconds and then enter low power again if no attention is needed.

I see no indication that the SGP40 has a low-power or sleep mode of its own.  You'll probably need to do that from the mcu side.

I thought about taking samples after n time, but this will also decrease the board's capability of fast response and it will not be instantly warned if something occurs.

Also low-power mainly refers to the idle mode once you exit measurement mode, if the sensor is continuously operating then it will consume more power. Although it is the main device that will trigger the MCU, I still want to understand if there is a strategy to enhance power consumption more

Yes, down to 105 µA from the datasheet:
"The idle mode is activated after power-up, after calling the sgp4x_turn_heater_off command, or after a soft reset."
As suggested in the comments, you need to write code to put your MCU to sleep with internal timer to wake up, activate your sensor, readout, turn heater off again and go back to sleep.
